# C# Running IronPython On Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, ironpython

I have a WPF app that controls audio hardware. It uses the same PythonEngine on multiple threads. This causes strange errors I see from time to time where the PythonEngines Globals dictionary has missing values. I am looking for some guidance on how to debug/fix this.

The device has multiple components [filter's, gain's, etc.]. Each component has multiple controls [slider's,togglebutton's, etc.].

Everytime a user changes a control value a python script (from the hardware vendor) needs to run. I am using IronPython 1.1.2(PythonEngine.Execute(code)) to do this.

Every component has a script. And each script requires the current values of all controls (of that component) to run.

The sequence is - user makes change > run component script > send results to device > check response for failure. This whole cycle takes too long to keep the UI waiting so everytime something changes I do something like component.begininvoke(startcycle).

Startcycle looks something like this -

```
PyEngine Engine = PyEngine.GetInstance(); // this is a singleton 
lock(component) // this prevents diff controls of the same component from walking over each other
{
  Engine.runcode(...)
}
```

When *different* component.begininvokes happen close to each other there are chances where engine.runcode is happening on different threads at the same time. It looks like I need to get rid of the component.begininvoke but that would make things crawl. Any ideas?

Comment: you posted this a year ago, but I'm researching solutions for a similar sort of problem.  Did you end up getting it to work?  I was thinking that it's not simultaneous access to the engine that's causing problems, but maybe you need to create a separate ScriptScope for each thread.  I'm curious to know how you ended up solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a EngineModule for each execution and execute the code against that.  Then all of the code will run against a different set of variables.  You also probably want to get a CompiledCode object and actually execute that against the new EngineModule each time because engine.Execute will need to re-compile it each time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this a while ago - creating new pythonengine objects. But when this happened on different threads at the same time it would crash. I think it was an ironpython issue. I think that was the reason I started using the singleton. Thanks for compiledcode suggestion.